# Drawing rectangle on a video with mouse in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I created a where I select a video using `QOpenFileDialog` and play the video on `QGraphicsView`. After that I select an area on video using mouse and `QRubberBand` class and want to draw a rectangle on selected area when I release left mouse click.

Since I'm newbie can you tell me which parts of my code is bad practice, unoptimized etc.? Is there a way to do it more efficiently than what I already have?

Note: I tried using `QVideoWidget` but couldn't drive anything on it.

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsVideoItem>
#include <QSize>
#include "mygraphicsview.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_actionOpen_triggered();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsVideoItem *videoItem;
    QMediaPlayer* mediaPlayer;

};

   #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

ui->setupUi(this);
mediaPlayer = new QMediaPlayer(this);
videoItem = new QGraphicsVideoItem;
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
QSize videoSize = ui->graphicsView->size();
videoItem->setSize(videoSize);


ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

mediaPlayer->setVideoOutput(videoItem);
ui->graphicsView->scene()->addItem(videoItem);
ui->graphicsView->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Select Video","","video Files (*.mp4)");

    mediaPlayer->stop();
    mediaPlayer->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileName));
    mediaPlayer->play();
}
```

**mainwindow.ui**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1268</width>
    <height>741</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="MyGraphicsView" name="graphicsView" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>848</width>
      <height>480</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1268</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionOpen"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
  <action name="actionOpen">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Open</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>MyGraphicsView</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>mygraphicsview.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**myqgraphicsview.h**

```
#ifndef MYGRAPHICSVIEW_H
#define MYGRAPHICSVIEW_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QRubberBand>

#include <QPoint>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QLabel>



class MyGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
    {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    MyGraphicsView(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
protected:

void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *ev);

void getCoordinates(QPoint leftTop, QPoint rightBottom);
private:
QRubberBand *rubberBand;

   QRect rect;
   QPoint startPoint, endPoint;

};

#endif // MYGRAPHICSVIEW_H
```

**myqgraphicsview.cpp**

```
#include "mygraphicsview.h"

MyGraphicsView::MyGraphicsView(QWidget *parent):
QGraphicsView (parent), rubberBand(nullptr){}

void MyGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{

    startPoint = ev->pos();
      qDebug()<<"START POINT!: "<<startPoint;
     if(!rubberBand)
             rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
        rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(startPoint,QSize()));
        rubberBand->show();
        QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(ev);
}

void MyGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
     rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(startPoint,ev->pos()).normalized());
     QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(ev);

}

void MyGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    endPoint = ev->pos();
    qDebug()<<"END POINT!: "<<endPoint;

    rect = rubberBand->geometry();
    rubberBand->hide();

    update();
    QGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent(ev);
}

void MyGraphicsView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *ev)
{

    QGraphicsView::paintEvent(ev);
    QPainter painter(this->viewport());

    painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255,0,0,0)));
     if(!rect.isNull()){
          painter.drawRect(rect);
     }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile: you're missing the definition of `Ui::MainWindow`.

Comment: @TobySpeight I just ran it on QT Creator and it compiles. Maybe its because I created the gui on gui designer ? Let me double check the code

Comment: Yes, include it in the editable form - i.e. the XML file, probably named with a `.ui` suffix.

Comment: @TobySpeight I added the **mainwindow.ui** can you check it now ?